# Fresh laravel installation not work in nginx server (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I just set up nginx web server inside my ubunutu 14.04 lts with fresh laravel project. My project name **laravel** and when I go to **http://localhost/laravel/public/** I can see the laravel welcome page display, but when I create an url to test it didn't work.

```
    Route::get('test', function(){
      return 'It is work!!!';
});
```

I hope when I go to `http://localhost/laravel/public/test | http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/test` it should display **It is work!!!** instead of this I get `404 Not Found  nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)`.
I don't know what is wrong?
I have `php7 ubuntu 1.4.6` installed in my machine.

Here is nginx configuration->

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name localhost;

location / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri/ $uri /index.php?$query_string;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

Please help me. I really thankful fro your help.

Comment: That's because the document `root` should point to the `public` directory, so it should be `/usr/share/nginx/html/laravel/public` and access it using `http://localhost`. [This article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) explains it very well.

Comment: If you want to run multiple website on your nginx installation I suggest you use Virtual Hosts like `http://laravel.local`, not subdirectories like `http://localhost/laravel`. You can read [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3) which explains how easy it is to setup a virtual hosts.

Comment: Hi @Bogdan! I really thankful for your help :)

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Bogdan already answered this in the comments. But for anybody else, make sure to point your document root to the /public directory of your Laravel project.

```
root /usr/you/laravelinstall/public;
```